# How can I use tikzpicture and wrapfigure and get text around the picture on a beamer frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, wrapfigure

I've tried the following, but now the last lines are not on the page anymore....
I want to be able to have text around a picture (hence the wrapfigure), have the picture scaled, and use tikz (code generated by GeoGebra).
But the text is not arount the picture, and so I loose the last lines....
Anyone?
Thanks very much in advance

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\usecolortheme{albatross}

\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Remove navigation symbols

\begin{document} 

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=white}
\color{white}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\frame
{
    \frametitle{Theorie B (12)}
    De lijn CD heb ik weer doorgetrokken naar E, het snijpunt met de cirkel. En ik kan hier weer melden dat $\angle A + \angle E = 180\degree$ en $\angle D + \angle B = 180\degree$ omdat A,B,D en E op de cirkel liggen en een koordenvierhoek vormen.\\
    \resizebox{5.0cm}{!}{}
    \begin{wrapfigure}%{r}{0pt} %[bla] is de hoogte in lijnen, {bla} is de uitlijning (links, centre of rechts reps l,c,r,  
    %\vspace{-12pt} %\vspace maakt extra of minder ruimte om het plaatje
    %\hspace{5pt}
    % \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
            \clip(-5.39,-5.34) rectangle (20.22,7.85);
            \draw [shift={(5.24,3.97)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (120.19:0.45) arc (120.19:191.53:0.45) -- cycle;
            \draw [shift={(5.24,3.97)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (92.9:0.45) arc (92.9:120.19:0.45) -- cycle;
            \draw [shift={(1.88,6.07)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (-85.72:0.45) arc (-85.72:-4.36:0.45) -- cycle;
            \draw(3.43,4.8) circle (2cm);
            \draw (2.09,3.32)-- (5.24,3.97);
            \draw (2.09,3.32)-- (1.88,6.07);
            \draw (1.88,6.07)-- (5.15,5.82);
            \draw (1.88,6.07)-- (4.12,5.9);
            \draw (4.12,5.9)-- (5.24,3.97);
            \draw (5.15,5.82)-- (5.24,3.97);
                \begin{scriptsize}
                    \fill [color=xdxdff] (2.09,3.32) circle (1.5pt);
                    \draw[color=xdxdff] (1.8,3.23) node {$A$};
                    \fill [color=xdxdff] (5.24,3.97) circle (1.5pt);
                    \draw[color=xdxdff] (5.51,4.05) node {$B$};
                    \fill [color=xdxdff] (1.88,6.07) circle (1.5pt);
                    \draw[color=xdxdff] (1.63,6.29) node {$D$};
                    \fill [color=xdxdff] (5.15,5.82) circle (1.5pt);
                    \draw[color=xdxdff] (5.27,6.04) node {$E$};
                    \fill [color=xdxdff] (4.12,5.9) circle (1.5pt);
                    \draw[color=xdxdff] (4.25,6.11) node {$C$};
                \end{scriptsize}
            \end{tikzpicture}
 % \end{center}
    \end{wrapfigure}\\
    $\angle ABC < \angle B$, dus $\angle D + \angle ABC < 180\degree$. \\
    Verder geldt: $\angle A + \angle ABC + \angle C + \angle D = 360\degree$\\
    Dus geldt ook $\angle A + \angle C > 180\degree$\\
    C ligt dus binnen de cirkel.
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was that the tikzfigure was filling the whole page.
There are still a lot of errors due to undefined colors.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\usecolortheme{albatross}

\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Remove navigation symbols
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document} 

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=white}
\color{white}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theorie B (12)}
De lijn CD heb ik weer doorgetrokken naar E, het snijpunt met de cirkel. En ik kan hier weer melden dat $\angle A + \angle E = 180\degree$ en $\angle D + \angle B = 180\degree$ omdat A,B,D en E op de cirkel liggen en een koordenvierhoek vormen.\\
 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
    \raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr \height-.5cm]{% wrapfigure likes to add a big gap here
          \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=Triangle,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
            %\clip(-5.39,-5.34) rectangle (20.22,7.85);
            \draw [shift={(5.24,3.97)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (120.19:0.45) arc (120.19:191.53:0.45) -- cycle;
            \draw [shift={(5.24,3.97)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (92.9:0.45) arc (92.9:120.19:0.45) -- cycle;
            \draw [shift={(1.88,6.07)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (-85.72:0.45) arc (-85.72:-4.36:0.45) -- cycle;
            \draw(3.43,4.8) circle (2cm);
            \draw (2.09,3.32)-- (5.24,3.97);
            \draw (2.09,3.32)-- (1.88,6.07);
            \draw (1.88,6.07)-- (5.15,5.82);
            \draw (1.88,6.07)-- (4.12,5.9);
            \draw (4.12,5.9)-- (5.24,3.97);
            \draw (5.15,5.82)-- (5.24,3.97);
                \begin{scriptsize}
                    \fill [color=xdxdff] (2.09,3.32) circle (1.5pt);
                    \draw[color=xdxdff] (1.8,3.23) node {$A$};
                    \fill [color=xdxdff] (5.24,3.97) circle (1.5pt);
                    \draw[color=xdxdff] (5.51,4.05) node {$B$};
                    \fill [color=xdxdff] (1.88,6.07) circle (1.5pt);
                    \draw[color=xdxdff] (1.63,6.29) node {$D$};
                    \fill [color=xdxdff] (5.15,5.82) circle (1.5pt);
                    \draw[color=xdxdff] (5.27,6.04) node {$E$};
                    \fill [color=xdxdff] (4.12,5.9) circle (1.5pt);
                    \draw[color=xdxdff] (4.25,6.11) node {$C$};
                \end{scriptsize}
            \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{wrapfigure}
    $\angle ABC < \angle B$, dus $\angle D + \angle ABC < 180\degree$. \\
    Verder geldt: $\angle A + \angle ABC + \angle C + \angle D = 360\degree$\\
    Dus geldt ook $\angle A + \angle C > 180\degree$\\
    C ligt dus binnen de cirkel.
\WFclear% to avoid possible problems on the next page
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer slide]

Comment: Thank you, this helps a bit, but (apart from the colour-problems, which I don't care about :) ) when I use your solution, it doesn't look like the frame you showed :(

Comment: In my frame, the outline of the presentation (highlighting the part of the presentation this frame is about) is in a bar above Theorie B (sorry, didn't post that, my bad)
So, there is less room than in the shown frame, which results in the drawing shown through the words.
Also in my frame there's a "r0pt" showing (and I checked, I typed it exactly like it was in your frame.....
As far as I can see, you added these lines:
\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr \height-.5cm]{
and a } at the end
\WFclear
Maybe I can solve my problem if I know what the expressions after the \raisebox do?

Comment: \dimexpr performs calculations, namely \height-.5cm.  The \raisebox was only added for aesthetics, to reduce the gap at the top of the figure.

Comment: Yes I know I can copy and paste :) (I did that :) ), but I'm still not sure why it doesn't work in my frame. I'll try to place the whole thing (okay, okay, not all frames obviously) here so you can see.....